# Convert Unix/Linux time to Windows FILETIME

Tags: c, porting, datetime-conversion, time-t, filetime

I am once again going from Windows to Linux, I have to port a function from Windows to Linux that calculates NTP time. Seems simple but the format is in Windows `FILETIME` format. I sort of have an idea what the differences are but so far I can not correctly convert my Linux time to the Windows `FILETIME` format. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

I have seen some articles on how to do this but they all use Win32 functions and I can't use them! I can post the Windows code if this makes no sense.

They also take the current time and subtract it from January 1st 1900 to get the delta to find NTP, I would assume in Linux I just add the

```
const unsigned long EPOCH   = 2208988800UL
```

to my time to get this result?

Comment: I do have a working conversion but now the problem is I need micro second resolution. If anyone is interested I can post the code, but now I'm stuck on the fraction of seconds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Microsoft documentation for the [`FILETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure explains what it is. The basic idea is that a Windows `FILETIME` counts by steps of 10<sup>-7</sup> seconds (100-nanosecond intervals) from 1 Jan 1601 (why 1601? no idea...). In Linux you can obtain time in microseconds (10<sup>-6</sup>) from 1 Jan 1970 using [`gettimeofday()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html). Thus the following C function does the job:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
/**
 * number of seconds from 1 Jan. 1601 00:00 to 1 Jan 1970 00:00 UTC
 */
#define EPOCH_DIFF 11644473600LL

unsigned long long
getfiletime() {
    struct timeval tv;
    unsigned long long result = EPOCH_DIFF;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    result += tv.tv_sec;
    result *= 10000000LL;
    result += tv.tv_usec * 10;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: 1601 because 1600 would be a leap year, and the business decision behind "should we add code to handle dates in January/February 1600 correctly, or simply start in 1601?" is pretty obvious.

Comment: explanation from MS Raymond Chen: [Why is the Win32 epoch January 1, 1601?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090306-00/?p=18913): *The Gregorian calendar operates on a 400-year cycle, and 1601 is the first year of the cycle that was active at the time Windows NT was being designed. In other words, it was chosen to make the math come out nicely.*

Comment: Still useful in 2023, in my case for converting code using time() for seconds to using GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() to include milliseconds.

Answer (score 5):

First, why 1601? Because the Gregorian Calendar repeats itself every 400 years, and the proleptic Gregorian Calendar starts with 0001-01-01. So 1601 was the last cycle start before 1980(1970,...) and that simplifies the calculations. (Oh, and that's why the 3rd millenium started on 2001-01-01, and **not** on 2000-01-01...)

To create something like a NTP time stamp with a binary fraction from a FILETIME,

1. Shift the origin of the epoch, using a LONGLONG or ULONGLONG to
   represent the FILETIME's ticks.
2. Do a floor division of the ticks by 10^7 to get the seconds (as
   quotient) and the fraction (as the remainder). If you calculate
   purely in unsigned, simply divide. But you cannot represent negative
   values in that case.
3. Unsigned multiply the fraction (which must be >= 0) in 64 bits by
   1844674407371ull, which is 2^64 / 10^7 (rounded)
4. Take the upper 32 bits of the product as the binary fraction of the
   NTP time stamp. (You might want to round from the lower 32 bits of
   the product. Note that a rounding carry into the full seconds cannot
   occur as long as the fractional ticks are strict below 10^7.)

Comment: This is the reverse of the question, but very useful, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you fetch the timestamp value from scrapping some website. You define

```
unsigned __int64 timestamp = 0;
```

The value you fetch might need to be divided by 1000.

```
if (element.HasMember(L"timestamp"))
{
    timestamp = element[L"timestamp"].GetUint64() / 1000;
}                                       }
```

then you do as follow:

```
LONGLONG ll;
ll = Int32x32To64(timestamp, 10000000) + 116444736000000000;
FILETIME ft;
ft.dwLowDateTime = (DWORD)ll;
ft.dwHighDateTime = ll >> 32;
SYSTEMTIME stTime;
FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &stTime);
```

Comment: Thanks @NathanMoinvaziri

Comment: I'm trying to use this to get a similar output in Objective-C to the output I get from `DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc()` in Unity. It seems like this should be exactly what I need, but when I run them each simultaneously, this function returns a number with a difference of around 252,276,759,470 from the Unity result. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: I tested that code on Windows / Visual Studio c++ and it never failed so far. If you find specific cases where it fails, let me know.